# Remove padding from img in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an img tag which has a padding around it. I use bootstrap css.

Please see the white background i want to remove that and make it sort of transparent. its already in a png format so i am thinking there is some padding around the image of container

[image]

code

used bootstrap.min.js

```
 <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center no-padding">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-15 padding-0">

            <a href="https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/HR/SitePages/Welcome.aspx"> <img src="https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/General/Community%20Portal/HR/SiteAssets/icons/StartHere.png" alt="Image"></a>
            <p style="color: #07ac8d;font-size:13px">Start Here!</p>

        </div>
```

Comment: I didn't get you ?

Comment: Please add some code more with clarification...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

png format does not gaurantee transparency, and css padding won't add an opaque bounding box.
Open those files in some image editing software and check out the alpha channels. [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) is quite a robust, free option.

You can also play around with css in the browser: in Chrome open the dev tools with Settings > More Tools > Developer Tools and "inspect" you DOM element.

Comment: the css is transparent, i have checked with Photoshop and i have added the   .padding-0 {  padding: 0;             } to the container and div with no effect.

Comment: Sorry i ment the PNG is transparent

Answer (score 1):

Those images may be in png format but i don't think it has transparent background, I think those images have white background, and also make sure that the element which is containing those images doesn't have any background css given. Because if it's given any background then your images won't look with transparent background.